# SensioFrameworkExtraBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and i'm trying to use FOSRestController to make an API.

Here is my config files :

```
# SensioFrameworkExtra Configuration
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }

# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
```

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Api;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as REST;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class MyController extends FOSRestController
{

    /**
     * @REST\Get("/some-url")
     * @REST\View()
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function getSomethingAction()
    {
        $view = View::create();

        return $view;
    }

}
```

The issue is about the `view_response_listener`, i'm having this error message :

```
(1/1) RuntimeException
You must enable the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle view annotations to use the ViewResponseListener.
```

Routing :

```
api_something:
    type: rest
    resource: AppBundle\Api\MyController
```

The bundle is already installed and added to the AppKernel.php file

Can something help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your posted config file clearly shows annotations set to false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your configuration of sensio_framework_extra :

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
```

Because the default configuration is `annotations: true`  (you can look at vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php)

Let the default configuration of sensio_framework_extra https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration

You may have forgotten to activate the annotations of serializer in config.yml (https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations)

I suggest you to try this configs :

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    ....
    serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
fos_rest:
    ....
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
```

Documentation of FosRestBundle view_response_listener : 
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/view_response_listener.html

Try to create the directory AppBundle/Api/Controller. And put your MyController.php into it. Your controller will be named

> \AppBundle\Api\Controller\MyController

Comment: Annotations of serializer is already enabled. This is working but I cannot use View annotation in my controller and i have an error message : "class does not look like a controller class"

Comment: your controller has to extend the  FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html)

Comment: he extends the FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController, I edit the post to add this part

Comment: Have you added the [route of type rest](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#single-restful-controller-routes) into app/config/routing.yml ?

Comment: yes i did, i see the route with php bin/console debug:router command & post updated

Comment: Try to add the directory AppBundle/Api/Controller into AppBundle/Api. And put your MyController.php into it.

Comment: OK, good job ! I moved the Api folder to Controller, and it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code to your main services.yml

```
sensio_framework_extra.view.listener:
    alias: Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener
```

Source of the solution:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1768#issuecomment-340294485

Answer (score 0):

another solution from [mentioned source](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1768#issuecomment-349239360):

in `bundles.php` the `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` must be located after `FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle` to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the same question with Symfony 4.0

**routes/rest.yaml** Routing configuration

```
app_admin_users:
    type:     rest
    resource: App\Controller\Api\Admin\User\UsersController
    prefix: /api
```

**fos_rest.yaml** view response listener enabled

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
```

**framework_extra.yaml** view annotations enabled

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:        { annotations: true }
```

**config.yaml** imports fos_rest and framework_extra

```
imports:
    - { resource: fos_rest.yaml }
    - { resource: framework.yaml }
    - { resource: framework_extra.yaml }
```